# Failed to pull image "levm38/server:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy a docker image on my minikube using a specific image:

But I always get this error

```
Failed to pull image "levm38/server:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF
```

I am behind a firewall but I already pushed the image, so I am not sure whats failing

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, have you tried checking if `docker pull` works within the Minikube VM?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems and solutions related to

1. Firewall
2. Proxy
3. Restarting and re-configuring docker

in this post:

https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2/23741/13

also,

do `minikush ssh` to the VM and see if you can connect/pull from registry on minikube VM.